# Maven EAR + WAR + JAR

Tags: java, maven, ejb, war, ear

I have 3 projects (using Maven): war, ejb and ear and I'm facing this problem:

My `war` project has a `ejb` dependency so I put...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.company.name</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>ejb</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

... and `ear` has `ejb` and `war` dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.company.name</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>my.company.name</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>ejb</type>
</dependency>

...

<configuration>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <version>7</version>
    <modules>
        <webModule>
            <groupId>my.company.name</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-module</artifactId>
            <contextRoot>/</contextRoot>
        </webModule>
        <ejbModule>
            <groupId>my.company.name</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-module</artifactId>
        </ejbModule>
    </modules>
</configuration>
```

During deployment I can update schema and create tables, sequences, but when I try to use a session bean I always get 
`javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MySessionBean` and it's funny because I see on console
`JNDI bindings for session bean named 'MySessionBean'` in subdeployment `ejb-module` of `ear`.

I've been trying for hours to figure it out what I'm missing, but I got nothing. Could it be the dependency scopes?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to say what was wrong:

```
java:global/ejb-module/MySessionBean
java:app/ejb-module/MySessionBean
java:module/MySessionBean
```

It turns I was using `java:module/MySessionBean` to acquire Session Bean so the exception was something like '..cannot find ear/module/MySessionBean', so I changed to `java:app/ejb-module/MySessionBean` and now it works!